# Gitlab 6.0 and clone repositories behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, gitlab, sidekiq

I have a new gitlab 6.0 server up. I've very happy with what it is doing so far. I'm building the core services for puppet and the gitlab is part of my version control system.

My gitlab server is behind a proxy server. When I try to use the web interface to import a github.com puppet repository, gitlab never finishes. In the ~git/gitlab/log/sidekiq.log file reports the following:

```
2013-09-17T17:15:32Z 3582 TID-ow55rv4zc RepositoryImportWorker JID-e6b23325fc3cbbacca286805 INFO: start
Cloning into bare repository 'opensource/puppet-puppet.git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/theforeman/puppet-puppet.git/': Failed connect to github.com:80; Operation now in progress
2013-09-17T17:16:35Z 3582 TID-ow55rv4zc RepositoryImportWorker JID-e6b23325fc3cbbacca286805 INFO: done: 63.66 sec
```

The main qustion is, where do I configure gitlab/sidekiq/etc to use a proxy server to repository cloning?

As an alternative I'm going to try to clone into a local directory then push to my gitlab environment. But I would like the gitlab app feature to work.

Thanks in advance!